# Convert double for-loop into a linq query

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, dictionary

I have a loop which, once simplified, looks like this:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<A,G>,Decimal> results = new Dictionary<Tuple<A,G>,Decimal>();
foreach( A a in collectionA )
    foreach( B b in collectionB )
        results [Tuple.Create(a, (G)b.groupBy)] += (Decimal) Func(a, b);
```

Is there a way I can replicate this result using a Linq query (with `GroupBy`, `Sum` and `ToDictionary` for example)? (as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11905618/529618) answer to a previous question: [Concise way to do a plus equals operation on a Dictionary element that might not be initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905539/concise-way-to-do-a-plus-equals-operation-on-a-dictionary-element-that-might-not))

---

**Result**

```
//Dictionary<EventGroupIDLayerTuple, Decimal> BcEventGroupLayerLosses
```

Using Yuxiu Li's answer below, I was able to convert this 4 liner from the linked question:

```
BcEventGroupLayerLosses = new Dictionary<EventGroupIDLayerTuple, Decimal>();
foreach( UWBCEvent evt in this.BcEvents.IncludedEvents )
    foreach( Layer lyr in this.ProgramLayers )
        BcEventGroupLayerLosses.AddOrUpdate(
            new EventGroupIDLayerTuple(evt.EventGroupID, lyr),
            GetEL(evt.AsIfs, lyr.LimitInMillions, lyr.AttachmentInMillions), 
            (a, b) => a + b);
```

into this one liner:

```
BcEventGroupLayerLosses = this.BcEvents.IncludedEvents
    .SelectMany(evt => ProgramLayers, (evt, lyr) => new { evt, lyr })
    .GroupBy(g => new EventGroupIDLayerTuple(g.evt.EventGroupID, g.lyr), 
      g => GetEL(g.evt.AsIfs, g.lyr.LimitInMillions, g.lyr.AttachmentInMillions))
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum());
```

And both yielded identical results.

Granted neither is particularly readable, this was a good experiment. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Should it not be `foreach (A a in ...) ` to be a proper C#?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what are you trying to do? what is that b.groupBy?

Comment: It's any property to group by. If you want the actual example and not the simplified example, check out the linked question.

Comment: Are you sure you *want* to use a Linq query here? Even the most "elegant" of the posted alternatives (and I can't come up with any better) is less readable then your procedural variant...

Comment: @PaulMichalik Realize that you have to `Add` an element to the dictionary before `+=`. This would be annoying enough in the procedural implementation.

Comment: @PaulMichalik, I agree completely. I don't plan on using the LINQ variant in production code, it was more a matter or proof of concept. I love one liners, even if the *maintenance-friendly* solution actually ends up being 10 lines, braces and comments included. :p

Comment: @YuxiuLi, Also true, which is why in the actual procedural variant I ended up going with the [`AddOrUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378664.aspx) method (normally only offered by the new ConcurrentDictionary class.)

Comment: `{Fast, Maintainable, Concise}.PickOne();` :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dictionary<Tuple<A, G>, decimal> dictionary =
            (from a in collectionA
             from b in collectionB
             group (decimal)Func(a, b) by Tuple.Create<A, G>(a, b.groupBy))
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum());
```

In declarative synatax

```
var dictionary = collectionA
    .SelectMany(a => collectionB,
                (a, b) => new { a, b })
    .GroupBy(g => Tuple.Create(g.a, g.b.groupBy),
             g => Func(g.a, g.b))
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum());
```

Comment: This is beautiful if it works (I will test it shortly). Can it be easily converted to something declarative? I'm not a big fan of the SQL style LINQ syntax in C#.

Comment: Did not know that it is possible to use expression in `group X by`

Comment: @Alain             var dictionary = collectionA
                .SelectMany(a => collectionB,
                            (a, b) => new { a, b })
                .GroupBy(g => Tuple.Create(g.a, g.b.groupBy),
                         g => Func(g.a, g.b))
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum());

Comment: @Alain basically the Jon Skeet answer is what you want :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want something along the lines of:

```
                         // Extract the key/value pair from the nested loop
var result = collectionA.SelectMany(a => collectionB, 
                                    (a, b) => new { 
                                        Key = Tuple.Create(a, (G)b.groupBy),
                                        Value = (decimal) Func(a, b)
                                    })
                        // Group by the key, and convert each group's values
                        // to its sum
                        .GroupBy(pair => pair.Key, 
                                 pair => pair.Value,
                                 (key, values) => new { Key = key,
                                                        Value = values.Sum() })
                        // Make a dictionary from the key/value pairs
                        .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

This is off the top of my head, and may need some more brackets :) I don't have time to add an explanation yet, but can do so later.

Comment: How? How are you always doing this so fast?

Comment: @hazzik: It was 12 minutes from the question to me posting an answer. That's an age :)